# spring boot 2.7.0 the thymleaf does not show authenticated user detail

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security, thymeleaf

The following code is the `SecurityConfig` class:

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationProvider;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.EnableMethodSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;
import org.springframework.security.web.access.AccessDeniedHandler;
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableMethodSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {

    private final UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    public SecurityConfig(UserDetailsService userDetailsService) {
        this.userDetailsService = userDetailsService;
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeHttpRequests(requests -> requests.requestMatchers("**").authenticated().anyRequest().authenticated())
                .formLogin(form -> form.loginPage("/login").permitAll())
                .logout(logout -> logout.permitAll());
        http.userDetailsService(userDetailsService); // Add this line to set the userDetailsService
        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public AccessDeniedHandler accessDeniedHandler() {
        return new CustomAccessDeniedHandler();
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        authenticationProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService);
        authenticationProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
        return authenticationProvider;
    }
}
```

These dependences are been added:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.0</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

 <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>nz.net.ultraq.thymeleaf</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-layout-dialect</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity5</artifactId>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

Now the issue is that, user can login with valid credentials, but in the view, `index.html` file, thymleaf is not showing the user detail.

```
> Logged user: <span sec:authentication="name">Bob</span>
>     Roles: <span sec:authentication="principal.authorities">[ROLE_USER,
> ROLE_ADMIN]</span>




<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
      xmlns:layout="http://www.ultraq.net.nz/web/thymeleaf/layout"
      layout:decorate="fragments/main_layout"
      xmlns:sec="https://www.thymeleaf.org/thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity5"

>
<head>

  <title>MSB</title>
</head>
<body>
<div layout:fragment="content">
  <nav class="pl-5 breadcrumb-nav grey lighten-4 z-depth-0 border-bottom" style="z-index:1">
    <div class="nav-wrapper">
      <div class="col s12">
        <a href="/" class="breadcrumb black-text">Home</a>
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" style="cursor:text" class="breadcrumb disabled">Company</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <div class="row mx-2">

    Logged user: <span sec:authentication="name">Bob</span>
    Roles: <span sec:authentication="principal.authorities">[ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN]</span>

  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

some update required:

```
     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
        <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity6</artifactId>
    </dependency>

  xmlns:sec="https://www.thymeleaf.org/thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity6"
```

clean and rebuild.